# PHP exploding a mysql row and getting size of

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$games = $row[Games];

foreach(explode(",",$games) as $game){
echo "$game <br/>";
}    

$row[Games] = 'Game1,Game2,Game3,Game4,'
```

I want to get the sizeof($games).  And it will work if it is less than 2, otherwise it will always be 2.  The output of the 'foreach' is this:

```
Game1
Game2
Game3
Game4
```

Comment: So you want to do: `count($games)`, but if it is less than 2 set it to 2?

Comment: You should check your $row. You have to add ' or " in your code otherwise its a  constant.

Comment: We don't know the content of `$row[Games]` so can only guess something you're using is inserting trailing commas eg `game1,game2,game3,`. [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) or [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) may be useful.

Comment: @ReactiveRaven last line ;) is the declaration... i think he would wrote it as new line.

Comment: As a note, storing comma-separated data in a database is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

`count($games)` outputs the number of items in the array.

Comment: While this is correct, it isn't the most helpful/complete answer. Try to take the time to explain how to use `count($games)`, what it does, etc and you will likely get some upvotes for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to count the elements of your array.

```
$row['Games'] = 'Game1,Game2,Game3,Game4,'
$games = explode(",",$row['Games']);

echo count($games);

foreach($games as $game){ 
    echo "$game <br/>";
}
```

You should is `'` or `"` in your array declaration. Otherwise you have a constant.

I don't know if your data comes from a database. But saving comma separated values in a database it no good idea. You should normalize your tables. Its very hart to change values of you have such a list.

Answer (score 0):

Use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to remove the trailing comma from the string first.

```
$cleanString = rtrim($games, ",");
echo count(explode(",", $cleanString))
```

outputs:

```
4
```

When `explode` splits the string, because of the trailing comma, the array looks like this:

```
["game1", "game2", "game3", "game4", ""]
```

and when echoed out on a web browser:

```
game1<br />
game2<br />
game3<br />
game4<br />
<br />
```

but the final line is not visible on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:there is a mistake in your array declaration.it should be $row['Games'] instead of $row[Games]

```
<?php 
   $row['Games'] = 'Game1,Game2,Game3,Game4';
   $games = $row['Games'];
   $game = explode(',',$games);
   print_r($game);   // output: Array ( [0] => Game1 [1] => Game2 [2] => Game3 [3] => Game4 )
   echo count($game); // output : 4
?>
```